# Were the 9 tails statues in Naruto legit?

Tags: naruto

So when Naruto was training to control the 9 tails, killer b took him to those statues where he said that if there was darkness in Naruto's heart, they would cut his head. When Naruto came out he said there was a switch inside and bee said "the statues were only there to scare him"

So were the statues legit? Did they really did the darkness detection, head cutting stuff? Could it be that they didn't detect any darkness in Naruto and let him pull the switch?

Or were they just meant as a horrible prank?

Comment: It doesn't seem legit, It more looked like a pranks as Naruto did to scare Yamato.

Comment: oh, so there was no darkness detection thing?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, I think it was a self test for Naruto. Bee was smart, and even though he believed in Naruto (that bump fist thing) he needed to make sure that Naruto wouldn't use that Tailed Beast power for ill purposes. So, he told Naruto to insert his head; if Naruto had hesitated because of those ill-deeds in his mind, Bee would've instantly stopped his training.